# SQL Server 2008 Installation on SP 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise, sql-server, installation, windows-server

I'm installing SP 2010 on Virtual Machine Windows Server 2008 R2. My Question: Is it necessary to install SQL Server 2008 (or R2) before installing Sharepoint Server 2010?

Plus, when installing SQL Server 2008, do I need to copy and install the setup in Win Server 2008 R2 Virtual Machine or that needs to be done in local machine?

Please guide. Thanks

Comment: Please be specific about if this is a test/development environment or an actual production environment. That will really matter for specific advice.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint has the option to install everything without you doing it.  But this will install SQL Server 2008 express.

To answer your question you don't have to install SQL Server 2008 before the install but you do have to have SQL Server 2008 (R2) installed when you go to configure SharePoint.

I try to install SQL Server on a different VM than the SharePoint VM for performance issues and would recommend that if you can.

You could install SQL Server on your local machine or the SharePoint VM or a new VM dedicated to SQL Server (This is the option I use)

Comment: Thanks Josh. I would go and install everything but SQL Server. I would install SQL Server as a seperate VM. For that do I again need a seperate Win Server 2008 VM machine?? Please guide.

Comment: First, is this a test environment or production!?! You do not need a separate VM. If you are going to use SQL Server reporting services in SP integration mode, install SharePoint first (don't configure) then install SQL Server.

Comment: Type of environment is important I was assuming test/dev.  I use a seperate VM for SQL Server so multiple developers (Or multiple farms) can use the same test/dev SQL Server that I can manage from one location but that is personal preference